# Is true that some vector spaces $V$ are not affine spaces $A$ because $V$ can also not acting on a set faithfully and transitively?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory

Every affine spaces are vector spaces
Not every vector spaces are affine spaces.

Why this happens? I read [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/884671/889588) definition of affine space

> An affine space is a vector space acting on a set faithfully and transitively

In other word, an affine space is always a vector space but why, in algebraic terms not every vector spaces are affine spaces? Maybe because a vector space can also *not* acting on a set faithfully and transitively? But in what way can you show me this using group theory/torsor?

But reading on wikipedia definition of affine space it's not a vector space that acts on something, but the reverse: a set that's acted on by a vector space. The vectors acting on the affine space are usually rebranded as “translations”. Technically an affine space is a pair of things: $A$ “together with” $V$, but the set of points is definitely $A$, not $V$.

I also take a look about [G-torsor](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/theory+of+G-torsors) theory because an affine space is a principal homogeneous space.

> Every group G can itself be thought of as a left or right G-torsor under the natural action of left or right multiplication.

> Another example is the affine space concept: the idea of the affine space A underlying a vector space V can be said succinctly by saying that $A$ is a principal homogeneous space for $V$ acting as the additive group of translations.

### Definition

Let $G$ be a group. The *theory of G-torsors* $\mathbb{T}_G$ is the geometric theory over the signature with one sort $U$, a set of unary functions symbols ${g\in G}$ and the following axiom scheme:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\top & \vdash (g_i g_j)u=g_i(g_j u)\quad\text{for all}\; g_i,g_j
\\ 
\top&\vdash (\exists u)\; \top \quad\text{(U is inhabited)}
\\
g_{i}u = g_{j}u &\vdash \bot\quad \text{for all pairs}\;g_i\neq g_j\quad\text{(G acts freely)}
\\
\top &\vdash (\exists x) \bigvee_{g\in G} gx=y\quad \text{(G acts transitively)}\quad .
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: You seem to have it backwards: every vector space is an affine space in a canonical way, but an affine space is not a vector space in a canonical way (though it becomes one if you pick a point to be the origin).

Comment: Vector spaces and affine spaces are entirely different objects. Affine spaces aren't vector spaces and vector spaces aren't affine spaces. You can construct an affine spaces from every vector space, though, and you can extract a vector space from every affine space.